# Use CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND for nested stacks on CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to use nested stack and when my ChangeSet is being executed, I got this error:

`Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]`

I went and create a pipeline with cloudformation.

This can be use to create a pipeline:

```
Configuration:
  ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
  ChangeSetName: changeset
  RoleArn: ??
  Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
  StackName: appsync-graphql
  TemplatePath: BuildArtifact::output.yaml
```

This can’t:

```
Configuration:
  ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
  ChangeSetName: changeset
  RoleArn: ??
  Capabilities: 
    - CAPABILITY_IAM
    - CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
  StackName: appsync-graphql
  TemplatePath: BuildArtifact::output.yaml
```

The error was: “Value of property Configuration must be an object with String (or simple type) properties”

This is the closest docs that I find: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateStack.html

It said: `Type: Array of strings` for capabilites, and the aws cli docs says similarly, but doesn’t give an example.

So I ran out of ideas about what else to try to have CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND capability.

Comment: In my codepipeline template:

1.
```capabilities:
  - CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
  - CAPABILITY_IAM```

=> I can’t deploy the pipeline. Error: “Value of property Configuration must be an object with String (or simple type) properties”

Comment: 2.
```capabilities: 'CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND CAPABILITY_IAM'```


I can deploy the pipeline but when it creates changeset, I got an error:

*JobFailed*
_1 validation error detected: Value ‘[CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND]’ at ‘capabilities’ failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must satisfy enum value set: [CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND, CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM, CAPABILITY_IAM]] (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError;)_

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm stuck. Thanks for reporting your results.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I tried another variant and it worked!

```
Configuration:
  ..
  Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
  ...
```

Comment: It seems that Pipeline GUI does not offer this option. While I was still experimenting with Pipeline I just needed a quick fix, so I ran `aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name my-pipeline > tmp.json`, edited tmp.json, removed the version and metadata from the bottom, set `"Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"` and recommitted with: `aws codepipeline update-pipeline --cli-input-json file://tmp.json`

Comment: That works, thank you. For info, make sure there is no space between `CAPABILITY_IAM,` and `CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND` just as it is in the example above

Answer (score 19):

I got the answer from Keeton Hodgson, this cli command works:

```
sam deploy --template-file output.yaml --stack-name <AppName> --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
```

Notice that there is no comma.

I still don't know how to change the pipeline template for it to work.

Comment: This helped me with my AWS CLI script.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the solutions above and what worked for me today (June 2020) using the higher level `sam` was adding a space between the capabilities listed. It's complete insanity that there's no resilience in this text file interpretation. SAM's cli is open source so I guess I could put my code where my mouth is and submit a PR. Anyway.

`samconfig.toml`:

```
...
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"
...
```

Then:

`sam deploy`

Output:

```
...
Capabilities               : ["CAPABILITY_IAM", "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the capabilities property at the very end like this

```
aws cloud formation deploy COMMAND --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

Change the order

```
Configuration:
  ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
  ChangeSetName: changeset
  RoleArn: ??
  StackName: appsync-graphql
  TemplatePath: BuildArtifact::output.yaml
  Capabilities: 
    - CAPABILITY_IAM
    - CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research found that you can actually add those capabilities in console.

Reference [Capabilities - optional section in the cfn deploy phase definition in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRtq3.png)