# cloudformation deploy capability_auto_expand

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, deployment, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I'm attempting to create a script to automate the deployment/updating of my SAM stack. I'm using batch to do this. Right now I have:

```
call aws cloudformation deploy --template-file "serverless.yml"  ^
--stack-name %1   ^ 
--capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND CAPABILITY_IAM^
--parameter-overrides   ^
  StageName=%1^
{some other parameters}
--role-arn {my role arn}
```

where %1 is the batch argument with the stack/stage name.

When i attempt to run this, I get the error in the cloudformation console that I need CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND to update some of my stacks. Looking at the documentation, it looks like aws cloudformation deploy does not support this capability? And aws cloudformation update-stack does not accept a filename for a template.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to sam deploy I figured out that it was an issue with the spaces before and after my line breaks.

Specifically I think I had too many spaces in

```
--stack-name %1{space}{space}{space}^{space}
```

then no space after the capabilities line. Cleaned up the spacing throughout the command and it works now

I believe that the biggest issue was the space **after** the ^

Answer (score 1):

probably you should use clean formatting

```
 aws cloudformation deploy \
    --region "${region}" \
    --template-file output.yaml \
    --stack-name "${stackName}" \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND \
    --parameter-overrides ;
```

Answer (score 0):

See answer provided by similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543397/use-capability-auto-expand-for-nested-stacks-on-cloudformation) and the answer relevant to the [cli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569096/11381520) commands.

Sorry would have used comment instead of answer but don't yet have privileges.

Comment: This doesnt work. I used sam deploy instead of aws cloudformation deploy, and put the capabilities at the end. and the permissions still did not work.